# Best way to get the information of a json file and use it

Tags: c#, arrays, json, class

I'm building an app in c# and i need to parse / create / edit / delete inforamtions (etc...) in a .json file. 
Underneeth is how the file .json will look like.

I was thinking of doing dynamic arrow of class (don't know if it is the way we say it in english).
Is there a faster and simpler way to do this?

Thank you very much!

```
{
  "name": [
   {
     "var1": string or int,
     "var2": string or int,
     etc..
     .
     .
     .
   },
   {
     "var1": string or int,
     "var2": string or int,
     etc..
     .
     .
     .
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Newtonsoft JSON should help you here. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: what is dynamic arrow of class?

Comment: If the data that you get is known you just need to use the [Serialize and Deserialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) strategy.

Comment: Did you mean "array"?

Answer (score 2):

First make two classes as follows:

```
public class Name
{
   public List<SampleObject> SampleObjects {get; set;}
}

public class SampleObject
{
    public int var1;
    public int var2;
   ....
}
```

Then try as follows:

```
public void JsonFileReader()
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("yourJsonFile.json"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        List<Name> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Name>(json);
    }
}
```

Note: Don't forget to adding `using Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: Note that this makes use of the [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for mentioning this!

Comment: You are missing a class: the original JSON is a single object containing a property `name` which contains an array of `Name` objects.  If you try to deserialize the JSON to a `List<Name>` it will fail.

Comment: @BrianRogers Please check! I have updated my answer!

Comment: Construct classes and deserialize [like this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IbqfYj)